# how to clear the content of one cell without clearing the boder/format in VBA

Tags: vba

I use cells(10,7).delete or cells(10,7).clear to clear the content of this cell. but the border of this cell also be cleared. how can I keep the border line while clear the content? thanks!

Comment: try `.clearcontents  `

Comment: have tried it, no effect.

Comment: No repro, `.ClearContents` works for me.